# Java, fast image warping according to own function

Tags: java, image, graphics, pixel, warp

I am going to warp an image according to the user-defined function in Java. In general, the image is relatively large (JPEG, 30-50 MB).

Initially, the image is loaded:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read("image.jpg");
```

Suppose [X,Y] to be the resampled pixel coordinates of the image,where [x,y] represent its pixel coordinates.

The coordinate function is (a simple example) written as follows:

```
X = y * cos(x);
Y = x;
```

My idea is to use pixel-by-pixel transformation:

```
//Get size of the raster
int width = img.getWidth(), height = img.getHeight();
int proj_width =  (int)(width * Math.cos(height*Math.pi/180)),proj_height = height;

 //Create output image
 BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(proj_width+1, proj_height+1, img.getType());

 //Reproject raster
 for (int i = 0; i < img.getWidth(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < img.getHeight(); j++) {

            //Color of the pixel
            int col = img.getRGB(i, j);

            //Its new coordinates
            int X = (int)(i * Math.cos(j*Math.pi/180));
            int Y = j;

            //Set X,Y,col to the new raster
            img2.setRGB(X,Y,col);                 
       } 
  }
```

Is there any faster way to realize this operation without any additional library?

For example using the warpRect() method in the Warp class...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `get/setRGB()` is basically the easiest, but also possibly slowest way of copying a pixel in the Java2D API. This is because the value for each pixel has to be converted from its native representation into a packed 32 bit ARGB format in the sRGB color space (and back again for the `setRGB()` method)..

As you don't really care what the native pixel data looks like in your case, using `(Writable)Raster` and its `get/setDataElements()` method is likely to be faster (how much faster depends on the `BufferedImage` type):

```
// Reproject raster
Object pixel = null;

Raster from = img.getRaster();
WritableRaster to = img2.getRaster(); // Assuming img2.getType() == img.getType() always

for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
        // Color of the pixel
        pixel = from.getDataElements(x, y, pixel);

        // Its new coordinates
        int X = (int) (x * Math.cos(y * Math.pi/180));
        int Y = y;

        // Set X,Y,pixel to the new raster
        to.setDataElements(X, Y, pixel);                 
   }
```

}

Note that I also changed the nested loops to iterate over width in the inner loop. This is likely to give better performance due to data locality and caching in normal CPUs.